# think i accidentally deleted some system information on my wd elements hard drive

Tags: boot, mount

### hi there everyone i have a similar problem to a post of 7 years ago,im having this problem for about 12 years now,problem with a hard drive
Asked 7 years, 1 month ago
Modified 7 years, 1 month ago
Viewed 55 times

Well I have an external WD HDD hard drive the format of which I've changed to FAT32 in order to work with my tv. Generally it worked very well and Ubuntu used to recognise it very quickly but today when I was unzipping a file into the hard drive, after a lot of time it crashed and plus my hard drive was not recognised any more. I connected it to the tv and after a LOT of time the light started to blink but it caused the tv to crash (when a unplugged it, it was ok). The I tried again on my pc and after some time the icon of the disk appeared on the launcher but when I as clinking it it didn't respond. Plus when I try to use the disk program it crashes and only when I unplug the drive it responds. I really need help, I have some really important file in there.

I think i deleted something on my Wd Elements hard drive my laptop reads it,it says something in computer it goes like this "Unable to access 2.0 TB volume
error mounting /dev/sdb1at/media/clint/-16DEA95BDEA93441:unknow error when mounting/dev/sdd1

I followed the computer to the tee incuding its grammar.Please tell me someone can understand that. Ican use the laptop,but only on my adroid tv,so much is on it I dont want to format it.Please Help me u commputer wizards i had this problem with it on windows and now on ubuntu

Comment: Sounds like a broken HDD. Of course, you have a backup of your really important files. If not and the files are really important, I'd recommend to consult a professional data recovery service.

Comment: You've provided no clear product/release details; though you do mention both windows and Ubuntu.  On any disk error I'd start with asking the drive itself for health stats (ie. use SMART technology of the drive; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  but you've provided no OS details for us to be specific with regards help (*no idea as to Ubuntu product/release details are known*)

Comment: hi there thanks fir the heads up,i did follow the system promtps as per synaptic massage i have however hit a hurdle as the the system icon apply has not lit up yet,  there are two fields not installed and not installed(residual config)do i have to mark them for installation as well,im a bit lost with this i as not able to re read the info as e have limited electricity supply here i did not want to use the laptop in case it ran out of power,please advise

Comment: I did use method 1  Method 1: Install Synaptic with a LaunchPAD PPA